# Multioutput custom keras ResNet50 model; ValueError: Graph disconnected

Tags: tensorflow, keras, graph, tf.keras, image-classification

In my code I am getting this error. How I can solve it?

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'") at layer "conv1_pad". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

My model is

```
def multiple_outputs(generator):
    for batch_x,batch_y in generator:
        yield (batch_x, np.hsplit(batch_y,[26,28])) #here splitting input data into 6 groups
   
image_input = Input(shape=(input_size))
base_model =ResNet50(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
m = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(m)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
type_out = Dense(26, activation='sigmoid', name='type_output')(x)
top_out = Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='top_output')(x)

model = Model(inputs=image_input,outputs= [type_out, top_out])
```

following I have mentioned `model.fit` section

```
history = model.fit(x=multiple_outputs(train_generator),
                steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                validation_data=multiple_outputs(valid_generator),
                validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                callbacks=callbacks,
                max_queue_size=10,
                workers=1,
                use_multiprocessing=False,
                epochs=1)
```

Please, can someone help me in solving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is, here I have done a mistake in model initialization.
Input_tensor should be added in model initialization.

```
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=image_input)
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer lies in carefully going through your Model Architecture and the nature of the error that you are getting.

Here your image_input is not connected to the rest part of your model

```
image_input = Input(shape=(input_size))
```

In the rest of your code you can see that every layer is connected to every other layer and you can traverse from each of your layer to the output
***But input_image is not connected to any of them***

```
base_model =ResNet50(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
m = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(m)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
type_out = Dense(26, activation='sigmoid', name='type_output')(x)
top_out = Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='top_output')(x)
bottom_out = Dense(8, activation='softmax', name='bottom_output')(x)
headwear_out = Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='headwear_output')(x)
footwear_out = Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='footwear_output')(x)
sleeve_out = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='sleeve_output')(x)
gender_out = Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='gender_output')(x)
```

But in your model you are trying to take `inputs=input_image` and `outputs=[type_out, top_out, bottom_out, headwear_out, footwear_out, sleeve_out, gender_out]`

But since your `input_image` is not connected at all the model has a disconnected graph with it.

So, try and connect your `input_image` layer with that of `base_model` or in whatever fashion you want and the graph will be connected.